# Ruby: Download PDF Invoice via REST API (e-conomic)

Tags: ruby, rest, pdf, download

I'm trying to download a PDF invoice via a Ruby script from my accounting portal, e-conomic. I use a REST API and I'm able to find the URL for the invoice PDF.

However, I'm not sure how I get to download it. If I directly reference a "GET" statement with the PDF URL, I'm able to print a lot of non-sense data (which may be the PDF itself represented in the Ruby output).

Any idea how I download the PDF file to a local folder on my PC?

Thanks,

Martin

RUBY CODE: Using the below prints the non-sense output as mentioned:

```
hHeader = {"X-AppSecretToken" => '[TOKEN]', "X-AgreementGrantToken" => '[TOKEN]', "Content-Type" => 'application/json'}
puts hTest = RestClient.get("https://restapi.e-conomic.com/invoices/booked/10000/pdf", hHeader)
```

Comment: Always use code tags when you post code on a computer programming forum.  See the first image here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoops, I answered the wrong question.  You can download a pdf file and write it to a local file like this:

```
File.open('some_name.pdf', 'wb') do |local_f|
  open('http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf', 'rb') do |pdf|
    local_f << pdf.read
  end
end
```

========

> I'm able to print a lot of non-sense data (which may be the PDF itself
> represented in the Ruby output).

Yeah, you can't read a pdf file like a plain text file.  A pdf file is a specially formatted file.  You can use the [pdf-reader gem](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader) to decode a pdf file:

```
require 'pdf-reader'
require 'open-uri'
require 'pp'

open('http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf') do |f|
  p f.read(100)  #Gibberish

  reader = PDF::Reader.new(f)
  pp reader.info  #A hash

  reader.pages.each do |page|
    puts page.text
  end

end

--output:--
"%PDF-1.3\r%\xE2\xE3\xCF\xD3\r\n7 0 obj\r<</Linearized 1/L 7945/O 9/E 3524/N 1/T 7656/H [ 451 137]>>\rendobj\r         "

{:Author=>"cdaily",
 :CreationDate=>"D:20000629102108+11'00'",
 :Creator=>"Microsoft Word 8.0",
 :ModDate=>"D:20131028152413-04'00'",
 :Producer=>"Acrobat Distiller 4.0 for Windows",
 :Title=>"This is a test PDF file"}


                         Adobe Acrobat PDF Files

Adobe® Portable Document Format (PDF) is a universal file format that preserves all
of the fonts, formatting, colours and graphics of any source document, regardless of
the application and platform used to create it.


Adobe PDF is an ideal format for electronic document distribution as it overcomes the
problems commonly encountered with electronic file sharing.

•   Anyone, anywhere can open a PDF file. All you need is the free Adobe Acrobat
    Reader. Recipients of other file formats sometimes can't open files because they
    don't have the applications used to create the documents.


•   PDF files always print correctly on any printing device.

•   PDF files always display exactly as created, regardless of fonts, software, and
    operating systems. Fonts, and graphics are not lost due to platform, software, and
    version incompatibilities.


•   The free Acrobat Reader is easy to download and can be freely distributed by
    anyone.

•   Compact PDF files are smaller than their source files and download a
    page at a time for fast display on the Web.
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the following code to save the file directly:

```
open('C:\Ruby24-x64\myfile.pdf', 'wb') { |f| f.puts( pdfData ) }
```

Comment: Sorry about providing an answer to a question you didn't ask. :( See the top of my post for some code that does answer your question.  Note that `puts()` adds a newline to the end of the output, which is probably harmless, but typically you just want to `write()` the contents of one file to another file.  A synonym for `write()` is  `<<()`.

Comment: Also, it sounds like the url may come from user input.  `open()` will execute arbitrary code that a hacker may enter as the url, so you have to sanitize the url and make sure there are no `|` characters in the url.